# Running/Building Yocto intel-core2-32 on 64-bit machine

Tags: yocto, intel, uefi, yocto-recipe

I have been trying to run [meta-intel](https://github.com/YoeDistro/meta-intel) Intel BSP intel-core2-32 on my 64-bit x86 hardware with 64-bit UEFI. I know that 64-bit UEFI will look only for bootx64.efi which gets produced and successfully loaded when using intel-corei7-64 BSP. What are the needed adjustments to run 32-bit Yocto Linux with appropriate Intel support on 64-bit hardware?